# RHEL Microsoft-ASR_UA / Mobility service agent for RHEL

Tags: rhel

I am running RHEL 8.8 in Azure. But the server keeps failing to install the Mobility service agent for RHEL  (for ASR).

I have looked but I can not find when I can manually download the agent and install it.

When i try to re-enable ASR protection

SiteRecovery-LinuxRHEL8

Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices.SiteRecovery2.LinuxRHEL8

Status message  Installation and configuration failed.

can someone point me to where i can get the agent for RHEL.